# What size UPS do I need?

Tags: power, ups

Trying to figure out what size Uninterrupted Power Supply (UPS) I need to keep my machine on in the event of a power outage (or on long enough to save what I'm doing before shutting down).

Needs to power:

- Apple Mac Pro (2x2.4 GHz 6-Core Intel Xeon) w/ a wattage of around 225W (I think)
- 2 Apple LED Cinema Displays (27" and 24") w/ a max wattage of around 100W each.

Needs to power those things for maybe 5 minutes.

Comment: I would get a [Kill-A-Watt](http://www.amazon.com/P3-International-P4400-Electricity-Monitor/dp/B00009MDBU) and measure it, be sure to provide a buffer of course.

Comment: What are the sizes of the LCD displays?  What wattage are they rated at?  How long do you want the battery back-up to keep the computer on?  Long enough to shut it down...How long does it normally take to shut your computer down?

Comment: @Kruug Just added some details for you.

Comment: @Shpigford What's the desktop rated at/what size power supply is in it?

Comment: @Kruug Added that info (as best as I could find from Apple).

Comment: @Shpigford this should work: http://www.amazon.com/Tripp-Lite-SMART1000LCD-1000VA-Outlets/dp/B000B651DO